# Spyder IDE randomly freezes

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I have recently switched to Spyder as my IDE. So far it's been great, but I've been having a reoccurring problem with it.

After using Spyder for some time, it randomly freezes and I am forced to close it via task manager.

It freezes while I'm trying to open a file, save a file, change preferences, and while looking at a code analysis error.

I have no idea how to solve this problem as there are no error messages and I have not found much help elsewhere online.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling both Spyder and Anaconda as well as using an older version of Spyder but nothing has worked. My operating system is Windows 10.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Are you using a Dell computer by any chance?

Comment: @CarlosCordoba No, I am using an MSI laptop

Comment: We discovered a lot of our new features in Spyder 4 are causing severe freezes in the editor. Most of them will be fixed in our next version (4.2.0), to be released in November 2020.